# Using Custom OpenSSL Wrapper Library in JavaEE Application

Tags: java, web-services, openssl

I'm planning to write a cross-plattform (Android, iOS for client-side and Java, C# on server-side) Library which wrapps [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) in an easy to use manner. The idea is to have a simple solution for integrating basic security features into simple mobile apps (we are not talking about banking apps) which communicate with a remote server over an insecure network. The whole package should include server- and client-side encryption functionality (not 100% sure if i should place this in one or two libraries. Maybe it would be usefull to split this up to keep the code more clean and the libraries slim).

I know there are other libraries around for Java and C++ which are easier to use than OpenSSL. Some C++ candidates are BeeCrypt, Botan, Crypto++, Sodium (a C library i think), [NaCL](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/) and [Keyczar](https://github.com/google/keyczar) (Google i guess, but didn't found much documentation about it). For Java: Conceal, BouncyCastle (Android build in), SpongyCastle, Cryptix and so on.

So far I'm not convinced to use the Java Libraries because i would like to use one library for all platforms (iOS doesn't support Java so i would have a hard time here). For the C++ Toolkits and Libs I'm also not sure because security is naturally a very sensitive topic. Idealy it should be some widely used, accepted, well-maintained open-source library. In my opinion OpenSSL does match this criteria quite well. I also like [LibreSSL](http://www.libressl.org/) but i don't think this lib is widely in use currently.

So far my plan is:

1. Write the basic wrapper in c++ for OpenSSL, adding some default configuration und easy to handle interfaces to the openSSL functionality
2. Add some JNI Wrapper around my c++ library and include this in an android app.

My general question is:

As soon as I got the JNI Wrapper, how can I include this result on my
server-side JavaEE Application (in Tomcat) which will handle the requests of the android app? What are the prerequisite? What should be configured? Maybe this is not possible at all. Am I to naive?

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Edit: 
Just to make things more clear: my final library will include more than just encryption functionality (also authentication and autorisation). Similar to [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, each platform has basic crypto libraries you can use on each side. For advanced uses including banking, military, healthcare etc with integrated key management and access controls, have you looked at [Crypteron](https://www.crypteron.com) ? Disclaimer: I do work there